# Converting a number from a certain base into base 10 in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, radix

How can I convert a number from a certain base into base 10 in Lisp ? 
Is any defaut function that can do that ,if not how can I buid that function ?

Comment: Related (going in the other direction): your question, [Converting an integer in base 10 into any base between 1 and 9 in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33634012/1281433), from 21 hours ago.

Comment: @AniFlorinAdrian That's a quite simple question, unless you didn't take any effort at all. You could google "lisp integer base" and came up with a solution quickly.

Answer (score 6):

In a comment on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635156/1281433) to your earlier question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33634012/1281433, you (implicitly) asked about this:

> *I need also to do the reverse function (to convert a number in any base into base 10) and i dont know :(*

I replied, hoping you'd visit the documentation, "The Common Lisp HyperSpec is very comprehensive. I'd suggest you look for functions whose names start with **parse-**."  To make this clearer, if you go to [P in the index](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Alph_P.htm), there's a function [**parse-integer**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_parse_.htm#parse-integer) that does exactly what you're looking for.  This is safer, in my opinion, than the approach using ***read-base*** and **read** in another answer, since using **read** opens you up to a bunch of issues (you can read non numbers, there can be read-time evaluation, etc.).  **parse-integer** does just what you're asking for:

```
(parse-integer "9" :radix 16)  ;=> 9
(parse-integer "10" :radix 16)  ;=> 16
(parse-integer "1af" :radix 16) ;=> 431
(parse-integer "111" :radix 2)  ;=> 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Base for integers are only interesting in terms of visualization and interpretation. Thus "10" is the visualization of ten in decimal, eight in octal and sixteen in hexadecimal, but the number does not look like that in memory.

You can change representation with `*print-base*`:

```
(let ((*print-base* 8)) 
  (print 10)) ; ==> 10, but displays "12"
```

Why it prints 12 is because when printing `*print-base*` is `8` while the REPL prints the result of the form after the `*print-base*` is back to the global value it was. You use `*read-base*` for reading numbers:

```
(let ((*read-base* 16))
  (with-input-from-string (in "10") (read in))) ; ==> 16
```

Comment: Be careful with **read**, though.  Common Lisp has sharpsign-dot which allows evalution from the the reader.  E.g., `(let ((*read-base* 16)) (with-input-from-string (in "#.(progn (print 'hello) 'f)") (read in)))` will return 15 (the value of "f"), but will also print **HELLO** (but arbitrary code could have been injected).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree. For just parsing integers `parse-integer` is better. A way to disable reader macros is presented in [Let over lambda](http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html) (search the page for "Reader security").

Comment: It's just a matter of setting [\*read-eval\*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_rd_eva.htm) to **nil**, no?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, but there are more subtle examples that allows some reader macros.